# except Exceeded 30 redirects if [] in url

Tags: python, python-requests

I want sent requests on URL "https://example.com/*/?parameter[]=*" but u get
`requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.`
if I remove '[]' from URL I get a response, but not the response (200 status code) I need.
All requests send with headers from browser.

```
r = session.get("https://example.com/*/?parameter[]=*", headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I guess to avoid this you should try this:

```
try:
    r = session.get("https://host.com/*/?parameter[]=*", headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    print(r.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    pass
```

Comment: if i use allow_redirects=False i get 301 response code, but i need to parse page

Comment: This website is protected by Cloudflare so I think that hard to break into it I will try some methods if it work I will tell you.

Comment: sorrt, but site dont have Cloudflare. I partially solved this issue, but I need it without using crutches

Comment: Are you sending a request to this website `https://host.com/` because when I access it I get Cloudflare, if not, mention the website you working on if you want, and I will try my best to help you.

Comment: that would be just an example)

Comment: If you don't mind sharing with me the website and edit your question cause you said that you sent requests to this `https://host.com//?parameter[]=`